# How to configure tinylog with rolling files in java using Netbeans or Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, tinylog

I'm using the `tinylog` in version `2.6.2` in Java Native Using IDE Netbeans.

This is my `tinylog.properties` file:

```
# Set up the rolling file appender
writer1 = rolling file
writer1.file = logs/SWI-{date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log
writer1.policies = daily

# Set up the console appender
writer2 = console

# Specify log format for both appenders
writer1.format = {date: HH:mm:ss} [{thread}] {level}: {class}.{method}() - {message}
writer2.format = {date: HH:mm:ss} [{thread}] {level}: {class}.{method}() - {message}

# Set log level for both appenders
writer1.level = trace
writer2.level = trace
```

Here is my Folder tree

My Folder Tree

[image]

Idk what's wrong with my tinylog. even I create my own logs folder in my project. However, I can see some log in console.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the screenshot, you use a plain IDE project without any common build tool. Therefore, you can put `tinylog.properties` directly in your `src` folder without any sub folders.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin. it works when I move the tinylog.properties to the src folder, as said on the page

Plain IDE projects without any build tools usually have no dedicated resource directory. In this case, tinylog.properties can be placed directly in the source directory. For example, in plain Eclipse projects the source directory is usually just src.